# How to setup Azure Devops Service Connection to Public Docker Hub Image

Tags: docker, azure-devops, docker-registry, dockerhub

I'm trying to setup an Azure DevOps Service Connection to this public Docker Hub Image Repo - https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet.

This is so I can use this as an artifact which I can create a trigger on as described here - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-trigger-azure-devops-pipeline-on-docker-hub/1601119?viewtype=solutions.

Can somebody advise how to complete the service connection form as it seems geared towards private Docker Hub repos?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you dont need a service connection for this, since its public. If you want to you can create an account on dockerhub and put the credentials here, this will help you with rate limits. But in most cases you wont have issus with rate limits anyway.

Comment: I need to to be able to add as an artifact (see updated screenshot in post).  If I create a DockerHub account, would registry URL be https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet ?

Comment: The registry is dockerhub. You can see in your first image the value is already set and grayed out. Thats the right value. Just put your dockerhub userid and pwd/token there and it should be alright. In your second image in the repository field, thats where you would put the repo ref. Its not the web url but the ref as you would pull it. Although the image you link is not actually hosted on dockerhub. They only use dockerhub as documentation page. The image ref is: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet`

Comment: From your image its not clear to me where you have this "Add Artifact" and what its purpose is. Hence, I cannot tell how to make it work with mcr.microsoft.com

Comment: Successfully setup the service connection.  Drop down for Repository is blank (as its looking for mine which there are none).  Tried typing "microsoft-dotnet-aspnet" but then got a 404 when I tried to start a release.  See updated screenshots.

Comment: as mentioned, the image is not actually hosted on dockerhub. So creating a sc for this wont help you. They only created an empty repo on dockerhub to host their documentation as its more likely that people will find it there. However, the actual registry is `mcr.microsoft.com`.

Comment: I feel like this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Perhaps change your question and tell us what you want to achieve. I see something with artifacts there but I am not sure what that is/ what its supposed to do.

Comment: Also tried "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet" but got a 503

Comment: The link mentioned in the original post describes exactly what I want.  Originally wanted it in YAML but MS say that isn't available so wanting to do it in a classic release pipeline - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-trigger-azure-devops-pipeline-on-docker-hub/1601119?viewtype=solutions

Comment: Yes, but they also talk about dockerhub, which is not applicable in your case. Perhaps doing something like a nightly pipeline is sufficient and more easy in your case. If not, you need to find out how to do that for mcr.microsoft.com. Which is probably not possible. You can visit this page in your browser and have a look.

Comment: The image is located here https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/product/dotnet/aspnet/about

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'll take away and rethink.